# Make A Button In JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, button

When I made a chrome extension I made a JavaScript file (.js) & html file, and in the html file I called the .js file through this line :

```
<script src='history.js'></script>
```

But I want to make a button in the JavaScript file not in the html

Comment: i want to know how to make a button in java script

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_pushbutton.asp

Comment: You can't have a button in JavaScript you can make one in HTML and use JavaScript to make it functional.

Comment: Where's the button, in the popup-page, options page, some page affected by a content script, some other extension's view...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
message = "Clicked Button";
document.write('<button id="mybutton" onclick="alert(message);">Button</button>');
```

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head><script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    message = "Clicked Button";
    document.write('<button id="mybutton" onclick="alert(message);">Button</button>');
</script> 
</head>
<body> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: -1: but you really shouldn't

Comment: I am just answering the question...

Comment: ok it works but if i want to make this button make a function ?

Comment: Make a function? Please explain.

Comment: i want this button to make alert

Comment: than Q But when i put onclick="alert('Clicked Button');" it doesn't work

Comment: Updated the answer, try putting the message in a variable and use alert.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using the `document`s `createElement` method

like

```
var button = document.createElement("input")
    button.type = "submit"
    button.value = "My Button"

document.body.appendChild(button)
```

heres a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ajaqoy/1/edit)

But that all depends on what you mean with "Button"

Comment: FYI, all modern browsers have a shorthand `document.body` for `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`.

Comment: Thx, didn't knew that =) Updated the answer